# Jest tests run through CLI but fail through Visual Studio 2019 Test Explorer

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I am using Jest with Visual Studio 2019in a Node.Js Typescript project  and have something happening that I do not understand, I would be grateful for some guidance so I understand what is going on.

I have Jest set up in a Node.js project in Visual Studio. npm packages jest, ts-jest and jest-editor-support are installed. Typescript file successfully compile in VS 2019.

When I use Jest from the command line, all tests run fine, those in the .ts files and also those in the compiled .js files, independent of which target version I set in `tsconfig.json`. No problem whatsoever.

When I use Visual Studio 2019 Test Explorer, however, there are 2 strange things:

1. With a target version lower then "ES6" in `tsconfig.json`, the build
   fails and I see that the babylon parser (used by
   `jest-editor-support`) throws a parser error on `foreach` and `map`
   statements.
2. Even with a target version of "ES6" or higher, when I use Jest's
   .each functions, tests containing these functions do not run
   correctly. They are shown as "failed", but in the Test Detail
   Summary window, there is no link to additional output.

Since Jest runs without problems from the command line, this means there is something different when the tests a re run through Visual Studio 2019's test explorer. How can I have the tests successfully run the same way in test explorer? (without the  detour through Babylon which obviously happens). I am looking for a solution of the failed test runs in Test Explorer, as well as, for understanding of whats going on. I am fairly new to Jest.

(btw same problem occurs in other project types with Jest / Typescript installed)

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @Timmo just upgraded all packages, including TS and Jest, to latest versions. Problem still persists, unfortunately.

Comment: I am interested in the reason for the downvote, since I sincerely asked a question after quite dome research and effort.

Comment: Had similar problem, but it was't Node.js project. Just a simple test inside asp net core proj that passed in cmd and failed (always) in Test Explorer. In my case problem was with test name - I used cyrillic, after rename all works fine. Im pretty sure you use English for naming, but, .... who knows.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was because when Test Explorer ran the jest tests it wasn't able to find the configs even though `jest.config.ts` was in the same directory at the root. So the solution was to move the jest configs to my `package.json`.

Here's my initial package.json:

```
{
  "name": "stackoverflow.tests.typescript",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.9",
    "jest": "^27.4.3",
    "jest-editor-support": "^30.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.7",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  }
}
```

So when I `cd` to my project directory and run `npm run test` or `npm test` it works great. But running the tests in visual studio test explorer always failed in 1 ms.

When I moved my jest config to the package.json like so, the test explorer was able to run my tests successfully, which I presume is because it could find my jest configs:

```
{
  "name": "stackoverflow.tests.typescript",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --config jest.config.ts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.9",
    "jest": "^27.4.3",
    "jest-editor-support": "^30.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.7",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "tsconfig": "./tsconfig.json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to modify the command the test explorer uses when running tests by modifying my `.esproj` like so but that didn't work:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Sdk/0.4.0-alpha">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>a509059e-5633-4f18-b58a-15b11d6a91sq</ProjectGuid>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <JavaScriptTestRoot>tests\</JavaScriptTestRoot>
    <JavaScriptTestFramework>Jest</JavaScriptTestFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Script Include="**" Exclude="*.esproj;**\node_modules\**;*\*.js.map;*.js.map;bin\**;obj\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="Restore">
    <Exec Command="npm install --no-audit --no-fund --no-progress --include=dev" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="VSTest">
    <Exec Command="npm run test" /> <!-- Test explorer wouldn't run this command -->
  </Target>
</Project>
```